# Go build error `signal: killed` when get dependency

Tags: go, go-modules

I was get some unexpected error when build my golang application `gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend` on gitlab runner.

The application `gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend` have a dependency on `gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain`, this is a private repo.

```
go: downloading gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain v0.0.12
go: downloading github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220411220226-7b82a4e95df4
go: downloading github.com/tealeg/xlsx/v3 v3.2.4
go: downloading gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2 v2.0.0-20150107220207-be2e0b0deed5
go: downloading github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 v8.11.5
go: downloading github.com/jmoiron/sqlx v1.3.5
go: downloading github.com/lib/pq v1.10.5
go: downloading github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 v2.32.0
go: downloading github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.2
go: downloading github.com/dgryski/go-rendezvous v0.0.0-20200823014737-9f7001d12a5f
go: downloading github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.16.5
go: downloading github.com/onsi/gomega v1.18.1
go: downloading github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.6.0
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.6
go: downloading github.com/valyala/fasthttp v1.35.0
go: downloading github.com/frankban/quicktest v1.14.3
go: downloading github.com/peterbourgon/diskv v2.0.1+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/rogpeppe/fastuuid v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6
go: downloading github.com/pkg/profile v1.5.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20200902074654-038fdea0a05b
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220412211240-33da011f77ad
go: downloading github.com/andybalholm/brotli v1.0.4
go: downloading github.com/klauspost/compress v1.15.1
go: downloading github.com/valyala/bytebufferpool v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/valyala/tcplisten v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.7
go: downloading github.com/kr/pretty v0.3.0
go: downloading github.com/google/btree v1.0.1
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.7
go: downloading github.com/niemeyer/pretty v0.0.0-20200227124842-a10e7caefd8e
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20220418201149-a630d4f3e7a2
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: downloading github.com/nxadm/tail v1.4.8
go: downloading golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20220411194840-2f41105eb62f
go: downloading github.com/kr/text v0.2.0
go: downloading github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal v1.8.1
go: downloading gopkg.in/tomb.v1 v1.0.0-20141024135613-dd632973f1e7
go: downloading github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.5.1
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/auth_token: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/vpn_managers: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/proto/v_proto: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core/auth imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/base: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core/auth imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/constants: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core/auth imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/v_log: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core/auth imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/biz/core: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core/profiles imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/cache: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/core/profiles imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/cache/memory_cache: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/dal/dao imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/redis_client: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/biz/dal/dao imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/sql_client: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/server imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/env: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/server imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/ip2geo: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/server imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/baselib/v_net/v_api: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/server imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/biz/core/auth: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/server imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/biz/core/health_check: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
gitlab.company.com/nood/monitor-backend/server imports
    gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain/biz/dal/dao: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
****************************************
******** building applications **********
****************************************
building main.go
go: downloading gitlab.company.com/nood/fountain v0.0.12
main.go:30:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/auth/session.go:30:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/auth/func.go:34:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/profiles/controller.go:30:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/profiles/controller.go:31:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/auth/session.go:31:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/route.go:30:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:31:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:32:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:33:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:34:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:35:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/core.go:31:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:36:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:37:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:38:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
server/server.go:39:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
biz/core/auth/func.go:36:2: git -c core.autocrlf=input -c core.eol=lf archive --format=zip --prefix=prefix/ 930e663b0f80f99e638c621bb72d599ce82f7531 in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3a00fbd5d1956a156ac1ad852b26361d0781eabcd35cb17623a25fdaf20a6fa0: signal: killed
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x scripts/env.sh scripts/build.sh && ./scripts/env.sh && ./scripts/build.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

I build my application on Gitlab runner(k8s:v1.23.5+1 + gitlab-runner:14.9.0) with docker with image `docker:19.03.0` using `docker:19.03.0-dind` service

`gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: docker:19.03.0

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  CI_COMPANY_PRI_KEY: $CI_COMPANY_PRI_KEY
  COMPANY_ECR_REPOSITORY_URL: repo.company.com
  PROJECT: tech
  APP_NAME: monitor-backend
  APP_NAME_ECR: monitor-backend
  IMAGE_TAG: $COMPANY_ECR_REPOSITORY_URL/$PROJECT/$APP_NAME_ECR
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - docker:19.03.0-dind

before_script:
  - docker info

build:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python2 py-pip
    - echo "Building image."
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TAG || echo "Building runtime from scratch"
    - >
      docker build
      --cache-from $IMAGE_TAG
      -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

`Dockerfile`

```yaml
FROM golang:1.18.1-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /app

ENV BIN_DIR=/app/bin

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc build-base git

ADD . .

RUN chmod +x scripts/env.sh scripts/build.sh && ./scripts/env.sh && ./scripts/build.sh

# stage 2
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /app

ENV BIN_DIR=/app/bin
ENV SCRIPTS_DIR=/app/scripts
ENV DATA_DIR=/app/data

# Build Args
ARG LOG_DIR=/var/log/company

# Create log directory
RUN mkdir -p ${BIN_DIR} \
    mkdir -p ${SCRIPTS_DIR} \
    mkdir -p ${DATA_DIR} \
    mkdir -p ${LOG_DIR} \
    && apk update \
    && addgroup -S company \
    && adduser -S company -G company \
    && chown company:company /app \
    && chown company:company ${LOG_DIR}

USER company

COPY --chown=company:company --from=0 ${BIN_DIR} /app
COPY --chown=company:company --from=0 ${DATA_DIR} ${DATA_DIR}
COPY --chown=company:company --from=0 ${SCRIPTS_DIR} ${SCRIPTS_DIR}

RUN chmod +x  ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/startup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/scripts/startup.sh"]
```

`scripts/env.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

go env -w GOPRIVATE=gitlab.company.com/*
git config --global --add url."https://tech_deploy:this-is-token@gitlab.company.com".insteadOf "https://gitlab.company.com"
```

`scripts/build.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

grep -v "replace\s.*=>.*" go.mod > tmpfile && mv tmpfile go.mod

go mod tidy

set -e

BIN_DIR=${BIN_DIR:-/app/bin}
mkdir -p "$BIN_DIR"

files=`ls *.go`

echo "****************************************"
echo "******** building applications **********"
echo "****************************************"

for file in $files; do
    echo building $file
    go build -o "$BIN_DIR"/${file%.go} $file
done
```

Comment: As an aside, your shell script contains several common beginner errors. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ though I don't imagine it will tell you that the Perl extension `\s` is not portably supported by `grep`.

Comment: You need the correct authentification for the private gitlab repository from INSIDE the Docker container.
That is two stepped. You might have a Proxy in your company. The docker container has to be sensibilized for this one.
Second you need the correct auth for gitlab. Here you have to know if its some official Gitlab repo directly from Gitlab itself or if it's hosted privately what Gitlab supports afaik.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you. But I was check, it is okay

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Don't worry about the authentification, that is correct absolutely

Comment: Not sure which check you were, but perhaps review [useless use of `ls`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: Fixed: Using Kaniko for Gitlab runner on k8s